# Access static selectListItem from multiple controller

Tags: c#, .net

I have a selectListItem in a controller that I use to populate a dropdownlist.

```
    public List<SelectListItem> BankSelectList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> Region = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "" , Value = "",Selected = true},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "North" , Value = "North"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "East" , Value = "East"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "North East" , Value = "North East"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "West" , Value = "West"},
        };
        return bank;
    }
```

Is there a way I can reuse this in a different controller without needing to declare the list again in the other controller? I dont want to go to each controllers to update in case there are any changes in the future. I dont put it in database because the probability of changes are low, and Im also trying to save on performace.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an Enum? And then create the select list in the cshtml file with asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BankEnum>()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the static class :

```
public static class DataStaticSelectList
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> BankSelectList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> Region = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "" , Value = "",Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "North" , Value = "North"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "East" , Value = "East"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "North East" , Value = "North East"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "West" , Value = "West"},
            };
            return bank;
        }
    }
```

And in your Controller to access the data :

```
var selectList = DataStaticSelectList.BankSelectList() ;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. At the first glance it seems like it's a good solution. But unfortunately the `SelectListItem`s are modifiable and also the `Region` collection as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above a static class could work.
You could also make a seperate class that provides you with the required SelectListItem collection via a specific method. This potentially opens the option to use DI and populate the contents via whatever dataset your using.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetBankSelectList()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "" , Value = "",Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "North" , Value = "North"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "East" , Value = "East"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "North East" , Value = "North East"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "West" , Value = "West"},
    };
    
}
```